# Array values Check inside for loop with condition in PHP

Tags: php

I need to check the array index and return array with specific values from api

```
$priceArr= array();
$groupArray = array('STD_NONMEM','STD_MEM','LOW_NONMEM','LOW_NONMEM');
foreach($groupArray as $group){
    $explodegroupname = explode('NON',$group);
    $customerGoup = 'STD_NONMEM';
    if(count($explodegroupname) > 1){
        if (strpos($customerGoup , $explodegroupname[0]) !== false) {
            $priceArr['non-member'] =  //price to fetch from Api;
        }
    }else{
        $priceArr['member'] =  //price to fetch from Api;
    }
}
print_r($priceArr);
```

I have values for each indexes of the array consider this are fetching from external api, values are like below.

STD_NONMEM = 250;

STD_MEM = 100;

LOW_NONMEM = 300;

LOW_MEM = 500;

In the above code the  customer group is

```
$customerGoup = 'STD_NONMEM';
```

So i need to return priceArr with member and non-member values from specific group

Expected result is :

```
 priceArr(
   'non-member' => 250,
    'member' => 100
 )
```

Right now I am getting below result

```
 priceArr(
 'non-member' => 250,
  'member' => 500
 )
```

I need to check if customer group belongs to STD, then need to return those values, if belongs to LOW, need to return those values.

Can you update me where i am doing wrong here, Please let me know if you are not cleared with my question.

Thanks

Comment: ?? `retrun $priceArr;` ?? RETRUN??

Comment: sounds like you'd benefit from creating a class with STD_NONMEM = 250 in and then you can reference it ..

Comment: @treyBake, I need to check if customer group belongs to STD, then need to return that values, if beongs to LOW, need to return those values

Comment: @RiggsFolly.  I updated now

Comment: @Manjunath that doesn't really reply to my comment .. o.O

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you got my issue?